# OpenCL find Max in vector of 1.8 million records

Tags: c++, opencl

I have to find the minimum and maximum of a vector with just over 1.8 million records in it, my current method is this:

```
__kernel void minimum(__global const double* TemperatureValues, __global double* C) {
int id = get_global_id(0);
int N = get_global_size(0);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (TemperatureValues[i] < C[0])
        { 
            C[0] = TemperatureValues[i];
        }
    }
}
```

but as a linear search this crashes the computer when working on the full dataset (works on a much smaller dataset of around 180,000 records). Anyone got any suggestions on how to adapt this to work for a large dataset?

Comment: Unfortunately OpenCL's behavior is implementation/platform dependent, especially it's undefined/crash behaviors. So please provide more info on your hardware and software platform. Also your memory allocation code, work group sizes. Full source code will be helpful.

Comment: And the style of your kernel code seems non-conventional (long sequential loop, single work item). AFAIK this style of kernel only perform well on a few platforms, non of which is a GPU or a multi-core CPU.

Comment: You are basically spawning 180k "threads" and each of them is performing one instance of the kernel. Actually this is 180k times slower than if you do it with a single thread. And it fails bacause it is so slow the watchdog timer kicks in. You need to make your algorithm parallel, currently it is not.

Comment: make reduction. each local group finds local min max. then a second kernel finds global min max by using local min max values. if local size is 180 and global size is 180k then only 1000 groups would have 1000 local min max values then second kernel would need only 5 groups using atomics or you could do that part on cpu fast. opencl 2.0 makes it easier with extra functions.

Comment: If you are not implementing for learning purpose, you can use [`max_element`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/max_element.html) function of the [`boost::compute`](https://github.com/boostorg/compute) library

Comment: Google "OpenCL reduction" because that's what you want. Your current algorithm is re-doing tons of work and won't be efficient. Think about a parallel algorithm; for example each pass compares two adjacent elements and produces one output; repeat that log2(N) times and you have your answer.